# Updating paypal call back URL

Tags: paypal, callback

We have recently moved our drupal website which is integrated with our CiviCRM database. We're having a bit of a problem getting our payment processors to communicate back to our database to confirm when a payment is completed.

Our call back URL has changed. The api.Paypal.com IP addresses have been added to the white list but I need to update paypal with the new call back URL.

I can't work out where I need to do that at all! Can anyone tell me?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you referring to IPN or are you referring to the Instant Update API in Express Checkout?

Comment: Apparently I should have been following these instructions but unfortunately this hasn't worked: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNSetup/#id089EG030E5Z

Comment: Sounds like you must have an IPN URL setup in either your PayPal profile or in your API calls to PayPal.  In either case, you just need to update to point to the URL where the IPN script now lives.